# Perl: XML Twig insert data

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have a settings.xml file as

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>server001</id>
      <username>my_login</username>
      <password>my_password</password>
      <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
      <passphrase>some_passphrase</passphrase>
      <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
      <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
      <configuration></configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

As seen, there is no proxy data. I would like to add data using Perl:Twig.
I cannot use other CPAN modules, as the perl distribution is not maintained by me.

I have read the [perl doc on twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm), but I am confused on the insert process. I have also read [this perl link](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=857284), [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503943/perl-inserting-an-xmltwig-node-with-xmltwig) where comparison/copy of XML is used (not relevant here because I am not not comparing). Also I read [SO twig child adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392089/how-to-insert-child-xml-twig), but I think I want to create a tag. This[So link explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301435/change-an-xml-file-content-via-perl-script) how to use XML::DOM, but I am limited to Perl:Twig, and lastly [this SO on XML:Simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299215/perl-script-to-populate-an-xml-file), but again I am limited to Perl:Twig, plus perldoc states do not use XML:Simple.

My current code looks similar to

```
my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots   => { proxy => 1 },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile( $maven_Dir . "/" . $settings_File );

if ( !$t->root->children('proxy') ) {
    print(
        "In your settings.xml located in your .m2 folder, 
         there appears to be no proxy settings \n"
    );
    print("Adding Jlab proxy settings \n");
    my $cp = $t->root->children('settings');
    $cp->insert("proxies");

#       $cp->first_child('proxy');
#       $cp->paste( 'last_child', $t->root );

}
else {

    foreach my $proxy ( $t->root->children('proxy') ) {
        my $port     = $proxy->first_child_text('port');
        my $host     = $proxy->first_child_text('host');
        my $protocol = $proxy->first_child_text('protocol');
        my $active   = $proxy->first_child_text('active');

        if (   $port == 1492
            && $host eq "jpoop"
            && $protocol eq "http"
            && $active eq "true" )
        {
            print("Correct proxy settings are set properly for Jlab \n");
            print( "$port \n", "$host \n", "$protocol \n",
                "$active'\n \n" );

        }

    }
}
```

Would someone point me in the direction of adding data similar to

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>jpoop</host>
        <port>1492</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

into an XML file using Perl:Twig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML::Twig isn't the best to edit XML, but it can be done:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use XML::Twig;

my ($PORT, $HOST, $PROTOCOL, $ACTIVE) = (1492, 'jpoop', 'http', 'true');

my $twig = 'XML::Twig'->new(
    pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile(shift);

my $root = $twig->root;
my ($proxies) = $root->children('proxies');

if (! $proxies) {
    print STDERR
        "In your settings.xml located in your .m2 folder,
         there appears to be no proxy settings.
         Adding Jlab proxy settings \n";

    my $proxies = $root->insert_new_elt('proxies');
    $proxies->set_inner_xml(
        "<proxy><active>$ACTIVE</active><protocol>$PROTOCOL</protocol>"
        . "<host>$HOST</host><port>$PORT</port></proxy>");
    $root->print;

} else {
    my $found;
    for my $proxy ( $proxies->children('proxy') ) {
        my $port     = $proxy->first_child_text('port');
        my $host     = $proxy->first_child_text('host');
        my $protocol = $proxy->first_child_text('protocol');
        my $active   = $proxy->first_child_text('active');

        $found = 1 if $port == $PORT
                   && $host eq $HOST
                   && $protocol eq $PROTOCOL
                   && $active eq $ACTIVE;
    }
    if ($found) {
        print STDERR "Correct proxy settings are set properly for Jlab \n";
    } else {
        print STDERR "Correct proxy settings missing:\n",
            "port $PORT\nhost $HOST\nprotocol $PROTOCOL\nactive $ACTIVE\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the clearly written example. May I suggest to add
  my $outDir = $maven_Dir . "/" . $settings_File;
  open (my $fh_out, '>', $outDir) or die "unable to open '$outDir' for writing: $!";
  print{$fh_out} $twig->sprint();

In case people wish to know how to write the new file?

Thanks again.

Comment: I would probably use `insert_new_elt` rather than `set_inner_xml` here I think.

Comment: @Sobrique: Sure, I'm not so familiar with all the Twig's methods. I'm more an XML::LibXML guy. Is there a compact way how to set the inner structure?